# Intellej creats xml files and uploads them to git

Tags: xml, git, intellij-idea

Help me please.
Created a new project.
Intellej spawns files without my knowledge and uploads them to git.
How can I fix it ?
I see these problem first time (I use IntelliJ for two years)

Thank you in advance.

Sample file list:

- _mac (folder)
- vcs.xml
- baseRefactoring.xml
- colors.scheme.xml
- debugger.xml
- filetypes.xml
- markdown.xml
- mavenVersion.xml

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmttJ.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean that IDE adds and commits without confirmation? Please check selected options under "Settings/Preferences | Version Control | Confirmation"

Comment: Also use .gitignore to tell git to ignore certain files